# Валидация даты в параметрах запроса, не отдаёт ошибку в swagger на FastAPI

Tags: python, datetime, fastapi, pydantic

Получаю и валидирую 2 даты через параметры запроса и хочу в случае ошибки **выдавать ответ в swagger**. Но swagger **валится в 500 ошибку**. Как починить то? :)

Пример запроса:

> localhost:8080/dashboard?start_date=2023-05-11&end_date=2023-05-11

Router:

```
router.get('/dashboard', tags=['Dashboard'])
    async def get_dashboard(date: DashboardDate = Depends()):
```

Model:

```
class DashboardDate(BaseModel):
    start_date: str
    end_date: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def date_validation(cls, values):
        if 'start_date' not in values and 'end_date' not in values:
            raise ValueError('Должны быть указаны обе даты')
        if values['start_date'] >= values['end_date']:
            raise ValueError('Начальная дата должна быть меньше конечной даты')
        try:
            values['start_date'] = datetime.strptime(values['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
            values['end_date'] = datetime.strptime(values['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
        except:
            raise ValueError('Указан неверный формат даты')
        return values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы получить 400 ошибку можно рейзить `HTTPException` и первая проверка лишняя, потому что поле по дефолту обязательное и ошибка и так будет рейзиться.

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException, status

class DashboardDate(BaseModel):
    start_date: str
    end_date: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def date_validation(cls, values):
        if values['start_date'] >= values['end_date']:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail='Начальная дата должна быть меньше конечной даты')
        try:
            values['start_date'] = datetime.strptime(values['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
            values['end_date'] = datetime.strptime(values['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
        except Exception as e:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail=str(e),
            )
        return values
```

Запрос:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?start_date=2023-05-11&end_date=2023-05-11
```

Вывод:

```json
{
  "detail": "Начальная дата должна быть меньше конечной даты"
}
```

Запрос:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?start_date=2023-05-11&end_date=2023-05-12
```

Вывод

```
{
  "start_date": "2023-05-11T00:00:00",
  "end_date": "2023-05-12T00:00:00"
}
```

Запрос:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?start_date=2023-05-11&end_date=2023-05%2F12
```

Вывод:

```json
{
  "detail": "time data '2023-05/12' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'"
}
```

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770979/how-to-raise-an-http-400-in-a-model) более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ